# How can I make a request queue to the server?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, next.js13, offlineapps

I am doing a project on nextjs app routing.  How can I make it so that if there was no Internet, the application would continue to work, and when sending a post request to the server, a queue of requests was created and when connected to the Internet, they were sent to the server?

What popular tools are there to solve this problem?

connected service worker